# How to search by advanced FAL metadata (tags)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-7.x, fal

As of https://forge.typo3.org/issues/69120, there is a file search field in the backend of TYPO3 7.6 LTS.

I would also like to give editors the possibility to search the "tags" field from `EXT:filemetadata;` (how) is that possible in the backend?

Answer (score 3):

Try this file search extension https://github.com/jokumer/TYPO3-xfilelist. It extends the TYPO3 filelist backend modul and the TYPO3 filebrowser to search within fields from extension filemetadata or metadata

Comment: Hey nice! Thanks! Would it help regarding the memory issues if I modified the extension and reduced the additionally searched fields (e.g. to tags only)? Or isn't that relevant?

Comment: As you like. You should adapt it, for your own needs. Keep in mind, it uses xclass, and you need to check and adapt this solution on any further CMS update.

Comment: I removed xfilesearch from GitHub and created a new one, https://github.com/jokumer/TYPO3-xfilelist which extends search for metadata and adds pagination for filebrowser